# Flask Python URL Stacking

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am currently trying to host a simple login form on a2hosting using Flask but im having issues with urls redirecting and stacking on top of each other. 
For example I have  www.site.com/index ask for a login or to create one. but when a user logs in or tries to register, the url will do something like www.site.com/login/index instead of just redirecting to /index

Here is a snippet from my routes code

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #submit to database
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

route snippet

```
 @app.route('/')
 @app.route('/index')
    def index():
       # variable containing a test text 
        return render_template('home.html', title='Home')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please send code snippet for index routing - @app.route('/index') ...

Comment: added a snippet

Comment: I try on my local server and it works just fine. Send also login to see if there is some mistake with @app.route('/login'). Also your def index() function is not properly indented, I got an error when I try to run your code with indentation like yours.

Comment: i think thats just a copy paste error on my part. One thing i noticed is that this doesn't occur on other sites like heroku or pythonanywhere. On a2 I see an error that the public_html folder cannot find register or login but from what I know flask serves static files from its own directory and the html renders perfectly. The stacking url only occurs after a post request is made and a redirect from flask is called.